# Getting results based on a timeframe and grouping by month

Tags: c#, linq, sql-server-2008

I have a database with a number of tables. One of the tables VersionBuild contains a date column. I get results using the following query and only select records that appear within a certain timeframe (eg. the last 6 months)

The code I am using is as follows

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-(timeFrame));
var grouped = db.VersionBuilds
                .Where(r => r.product_id == id && r.date > startDate)
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.date.Year, r.date.Month })
                .Select(r => new { 
                    month = getMonthName(r.Key.Month), 
                    totalIssues = r.Sum(zz => zz.AcrolinxReport.total_issues) 
                });
return grouped;
```

The one problem with the code is that if there are no records for a particular month, it ignores it. I am displaying the returned information in a chart so this leaves a gap in the data. For example if I have records in the month of May and June, it will return data for may and june but what I want is to return data for all months in the specified timeframe, regardless of if there is any data for them or not.

Comment: Check the date that comes out the database. I think it's Unix time in mysql

Comment: Sorry, my mistake this database is using SQL Server 2008 R2, not MySql

Comment: In my opinion you either need to pass all the months in advance and do some equivalent of a join (may not be actual join) or process the results after the query. I would do the latter.

Comment: Once you've retrieved your data, you can go through and insert the missing months in with a for loop or something

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this will work for you.  It was difficult to test without data but I think you should not have any problems.

```
// Assume 'timeframe' is a positive integer.

// Get the start date.
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-timeframe);

// Generate a list of months (year and month, actually) beginning 
// with the month of 'startDate'.
var months =
    Enumerable
    .Range(0, timeframe)
    .Select(x => startDate.AddMonths(x))
    .Select(x => new { x.Year, x.Month });

// Create builds query.
var builds =
    db.VersionBuilds
    .Where(r => r.product_id == id && r.date > startDate)
    .GroupBy(r => new { r.date.Year, r.date.Month })
    .Select(r => new { 
        Month = r.Key.Month,
        Year = r.Key.Year,
        TotalIssues = r.Sum(zz => zz.AcrolinxReport.total_issues));

// Join 'months' on 'builds'
var grouped =
    months
    .GroupJoin(
        builds.AsEnumerable(),
        date => date,
        build => new { build.Year, build.Month },
        (date, buildGroup) => new { 
            date.Year, 
            date.Month, 
            TotalIssues = buildGroup.Sum(x => x.TotalIssues) })
    .OrderBy(x => x.Year)
    .ThenBy(x => x.Month)
    .Select(x => new { Month = getMonth(x.Month), x.TotalIssues });
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try something like this:

First, we create a list with all months in the given time frame
For instance, if we run this now and set as a timeFrame to be 3, then 
This list would contain the following datetimes

- 2015-08-15 ....,
- 2015-07-15 ....,
- 2015-06-15

Here is the code:

```
var monthsInTimeFrame = new List<DateTime>();
for(int i = timeFrame; i>=0 ; i--)
{ 
    monthsInTimeFrame.Add(DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-i));
}
```

Then you keep fetching your data the way you have already dome,
but with a minor change. Instead of creating a list of objects of an 
anonymous type, you create a list of objects of a named typed. I picked the vague name `Data`. You could had picked whatever name you want. Furthermore, this type would have two extra properties one the `Year` and the other the `Month`. We need them, in order to identify if a specific month from the *expected* months are in the list.

```
DateTime startDate = DateTime.Now.AddMonths(-(timeFrame));
var grouped = db.VersionBuilds
                .Where(r => r.product_id == id && r.date > startDate)
                .GroupBy(r => new { r.date.Year, r.date.Month })
                .Select(r => new Data
                { 
                    Year = r.Key.Name,
                    Month = r.Key.Month,
                    MonthName = getMonthName(r.Key.Month), 
                    TotalIssues = r.Sum(zz => zz.AcrolinxReport.total_issues) 
                }).ToList();
```

Notice that we have to call the `ToList` at the end of our query, because below we will make use of the `Add` method to add the missing months.

Last, we have to loop through the items of the `monthsInTimeFrame`:

```
foreach(var month in monthsInTimeFrame)
{
    // If there isn't any item in the list called
    // grouped with the same year and month of the current month,
    // we have to add a new item in this list       
    if(!grouped.Any(item=>item.Year==month.Year &&
                          item.Month==month.Month)) 
        grouped.Add(new Data
        { 
            Year = month.Year, 
            Month = month.Month,
            MonthName = getMonthName(month.Month), 
            TotalIssues = 0 
        });
}
return grouped;
```

The definition of the `Data` class could have been this:

```
public class Data
{
    public int Year { get; set; }
    public int Month { get; set; }
    public string MonthName { get; set; }
    public int TotalIssues { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: @Alan you are welcome dude ! I am glad that I helped.